# Reports of Multi-geo enabled tenant using graph api

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, microsoft-graph, tenant

how do I get the Usage report in multi-geo enabled tenant ?
do I required to collect Usage Report for every tenant (default tenant and other satellite tenant manually ?